# Runtime error VBA 32813 Deleting a sheet and naming a new sheet with the same name (CodeName)

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro of importing a sheet to a workbook.
Checks if the sheet with a codename HQ exists, and if yes deletes it, and runs a data filtering.

```
Sub mainroll()
filename = some path
SheetByCodename("HQA"), Workbooks("blahblah.xlsm")
For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
total = Workbooks("blahblah.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
after:=Workbooks("blahblah.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
Workbooks("LMS Tool.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents(Sheets(sheet.Name).CodeName).Name = "HQA"
Next sheet
HQ_Clean
End Sub



Sub SheetByCodename(nm As String, wb As Workbook)
Dim ws As Object
If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.CodeName = nm Then
        ws.Delete
        Exit Function
    End If
Next ws
End Sub

Sub HQ_clean()

Last = HQA.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
HQA.Range("A1:AB" & Last).AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="PA"
Set MYsht = ActiveSheet   
LastRow =MYsht.UsedRange.Rows(MYsht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1

If Rows(i).Hidden = True Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

Next

HQA.Range("B:B,E:E,H:N,P:AB").EntireColumn.Delete

If HQA.AutoFilterMode Then HQA.AutoFilterMode = False
Set MYsht = Nothing

End Sub
```

To the error a i need help with, i seem to be running into a Method Name out of object _VB component 32813 error. I believe the vba components objects doesnt update during the run, so it thinks HQ sheet exists after i deleted it (so it doenst let me create a new sheet with the same codename).

UPDATED Troubleshoot. if i comment out the HQ_Clean it works perfectly, but if i run it with HQ_clean it gives me the error. What in HQ_Clean messes up my workbook?
CONTEXT: i run the program twice - without the HQ_clean it runs perfectly. With HQ_clean in - the first time (when HQA sheet doenst exist yet) it works, but on the second run i receive the error.

Comment: Do you call SheetByCodename at all? Do you pass `"HQ"` as first parameter?  Do you pass `Workbooks("blahblah.xlsm")` as second parameter?  - I did a quick test and had no issues deleting and creating a sheet with the same code name.

Comment: @urdearboy: Why do you think that this is an UDF? But one thing is true: `SheetByCodename` should be a Sub, not a Function as it never returns anything.

Comment: Sure, me either, but it's a regular function, not an UDF

Comment: Yeah, my bad on using a function instead of a sub. But the error still exists. What is a UDF?

Comment: UDF: User Defined Function. A function that you use in an Excel-Sheet as part of a formula, like a build-in function. It has some limitations compared to normal functions (or subs), eg it may not change the content or formatting of cells.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to a proper sub. The error is still occurring with a _vb components.

Comment: Again my question: Do you call the (now sub) `SheetByCodename` with the correct parameters so that the sheet is deleted before recreated? You don't show the call of the sub. If you omit the 2nd parameter, the sheet is searched and deleted (if it exists) in `ThisWorkbook` and that is likely not `blahblah.xlsm`.

Comment: @FunThomas Yes, im using the correct inputs. Please see my edits above.

Comment: `SheetByCodename` ignores the passed-in workbook, and always operates on `ThisWorkbook`...  This `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` should be `For Each ws In wb.Worksheets`

Comment: I have added the application.screenupdating = True after I call sheetbycodename, and I can see that the sheet was deleted in the workbook but it still listed in the VBA Excel objects.

Comment: Where are these codes located? In `blahblah.xlsm`, in `Workbooks(fileName)` or in a third workbook? Why don't you share more relevant code, I mean you can't delete the worksheet without a certain dialog appearing unless you set `Application.DisplayAlerts` to `False` which would make it relevant.

Comment: You delete the sheet from `blahblah.xlsm`, you add a new sheet in `blahblah.xlsm` but you set the codename of a sheet of `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Updated the code and did some more troubleshooting. Narrowed it down the the post process clean. See above notes "Updated Troubleshoot".

Comment: It is still unclear what needs to be done. I concluded that you want to copy a source worksheet to a destination workbook but previously, in the destination workbook, you want to delete a worksheet with the same code name as the code name of the source worksheet. If so, you don't need to change the code name of the copied worksheet, it has already the correct code name. If not, why don't you accurately explain what needs to be copied and where, for each worksheet, sharing its workbook name, name, and code name? Also, you should explain what `Workbooks(fileName)` and `ActiveSheet` are.